# Problem with saving products Prestashop 1.6.1.17

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Goodmorning everyone,

I'm having an error that I can not fix on Prestashop, version 1.6.1.17, when I saving the products.

In practice when I going to save I get the two errors on validation:

The product must be in at least one category.
This product must be in at least one default category.

From Javascript side there is an error, but I read in several other threads that is "normal".
[image]

The product can not retrieve the associated category and the only way to set it again is to use the search field in the association tab.
[image]

In this way I can save the product, but if I return to edit the problem obviously reoccurs.

I tried to find solutions everywhere but I did not find anything that worked, someone has ideas on how to try to solve?

Thanks so much!

Comment: The behavior may have been changed from a module, modifications in the core files, override files, or an error. You can start by disabling all the override files and the non native modules and see what happen, also turn on the debug mode should help to find an error (in case of).

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why it worked, but after regenerating the admin user I solved the problem.

If anyone has any idea what may have happened, I'm curious to understand the cause of this anomaly.